# Avoiding manual server file management

Tags: server, task, development-environment

I have an interesting dev requirement that i've been trying to find a decent solution to for some time. I thought I might look here for suggestions.

I have 4 server locations on a network drive: 2 for development, 2 for production. each pair is intended to be identical, though because we're manually managing files gaps often surface. Developing in this context goes like this:

1. Make changes on one dev server.
2. Copy the updated files to the other dev server.
3. preview in browser.
4. repeat as necessary until ready to go live.
5. copy files from one dev server to one prod server, then the other.
6. review and test and hope to got you remember all the dependancies.
7. Realize that something is missing in a stylesheet somewhere because a colleague missed a server 6 months ago.
8. commence swearing. lather. rinse. repeat.

The closest thing to a solution I've been able to get to thus far involved using the local/remote server setup with autosave in dreamweaver with mappings to the two dev servers. But all this stuff being over a network makes things slow. And dreamweaver is far from my favorite editor.

I'd love to be able to find some way of making this better. In my freelance stuff I've been getting into things like NPM and Grunt, and I'm convinced I might be able to do something with something along the lines of task automation as is seen there, but I'm not experienced enough with these yet to know if that's a direction I should be considering.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any source control system you like to achieve what you want. Git seems to be the most popular choice those days, but even CVS would do the trick

Comment: I've never worked with Git before, but I think that might be the way to go. Trouble will be getting my colleagues to buy in, and learning it to begin with.